# make input element draggable after disabling it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have an `<input>` element which I have "disabled" (using `disabled:true`) and for which I have removed selection (using  `.disableSelection()`).

The `<input>` element is therefore not much more than a picture: non-interactive pixels. Because of that, I should be able to make the element draggable, as there is no chance of conflict with any another `click` event.

I've tried `.draggable()` naively, but that doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/E26dY/

Comment: So you have only disabled it because you want the `input` to become draggable right?

Comment: Essentially. Any better approaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to un-disable `input` and then use `.draggable({cancel: null})` in your js. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/E26dY/8/

**HTML:**

```
<input />
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:**

```
$('input').val('Drag me!').disableSelection().css('webkit-user-select','none').draggable({cancel: null});
```